# HasLayout (or some other IE7) bug?

Tags: css, debugging, syntax

I'm having some trouble getting large background images I have for a site in development to show these background images.  I'm wondering is it a hasLayout bug or something else?

I don't have access to an IE7 box with any kind of debugging / developer tools.  A testing environment has been prepared for this project and can be viewed here:

http://samira.dreamstarstudios.net/

on line 54 of the main `style.css` file you can find the following code for the CSS background:

`.parent-pageid-128 #bg_samira, #bg_samira {
background: url('../img/bg_samira_home.jpg')no-repeat top center;
}`

Anyone able to see a bug that I'm missing?

Comment: With IE9 development tools you can run quirks, IE7 and IE8 simulations.. this might help http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: I can see there's no space before 'no-repeat'. This could affect things, maybe.

Comment: @james6848 You were right - it was the missing space, post it as an answer if you want to get credit for it, otherwise I'll delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing space before `no-repeat` in the background property